# How to replace higher-than-threshold values by the median of previous 3 rows (30 minutes interval) within a group in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
col1 col2                   col3    col4 
A    2021-03-28 02:40:00    1.50    0.0
A    2021-03-28 02:40:00    1.80    0.0
A    2021-03-28 02:50:00    0.50    0.0
A    2021-03-28 03:00:00    10.00   0.0
A    2021-03-28 03:10:00    0.00    0.0
A    2021-03-28 03:20:00    0.00    0.0
A    2021-03-28 03:30:00    0.14    0.0
```

All `col3` values that are greater than 5 should be replaced with the median of the past 30 minutes, which corresponds to the previous 3 rows.

Expected result:

```
col1 col2                   col3    col4 
A    2021-03-28 02:40:00    1.50    0.0
A    2021-03-28 02:40:00    1.80    0.0
A    2021-03-28 02:50:00    0.50    0.0
A    2021-03-28 03:00:00    1.50   0.0
A    2021-03-28 03:10:00    0.00    0.0
A    2021-03-28 03:20:00    0.00    0.0
A    2021-03-28 03:30:00    0.14    0.0
```

Thus, the value 10 in `col3` was substituted by `1.5`, which is the median of previous 3 rows: `np.median([1.5, 1.8, 0.5])`.

How can I automate it for the whole DataFrame.

Comment: So the time are always 10 mins apart that every time 3 rows get picked up?  You need conditon based on time or only last 3 rows?

Comment: @Ank: 1 row always means 10 minutes. Thus. 3 rows condition is equal to 30 minutes.

Comment: Using `.rolling('30T'` would set a 30 minutes window without assuming whether the data is  5 mins, 10 mins apart, or 15 minutes apart.  It would still get the correct number of intervals to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can break it into 2 parts:

1. The first part on calculation of the median of the past 30 minutes, which corresponds to the previous 3 rows (within the grouping of `col1`)
2. The second part on filtering on condition higher than threshold in order to get the new values.

**1st Part**:  You can use [`.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to get a rolling window of past 30 minutes and then use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply the `np.median` function on this rolling window.  Then [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) so that we get the entry of previous row.

Here we use a rolling window of `30T` instead of fixed number of intervals as the window size.  This notion has the advantage that your data is not constrained to consistent and fixed 5 mins, 10 minutes or 15 minutes intervals. So long as you want to calculate for 30 minutes, Pandas would get the correct number of intervals to work on.

As the time sequence in `col2` is for the scope of a specific value of `col1` (probably some kind of grouping), we have to further use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `col1` to process the time sequence in segments for each `col1` grouping accordingly.

**2nd Part**: We use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) on condition of  `df['col3'] > threshold`, and if condition holds true, we replace with value of those calculated in 1st part.

Here's the codes:

```
df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col2'])  

threshold = 5
df['col3'] = (df['col3'].mask(
                 df['col3'] > threshold, 
                 df.groupby('col1')
                   .rolling('30T', on='col2')['col3']
                   .apply(lambda x: np.median(x))
                   .shift()
                   .reset_index()['col3'])
             )
```

Result:

```
print(df)


  col1                col2  col3  col4
0    A 2021-03-28 02:40:00  1.50   0.0
1    A 2021-03-28 02:40:00  1.80   0.0
2    A 2021-03-28 02:50:00  0.50   0.0
3    A 2021-03-28 03:00:00  1.50   0.0
4    A 2021-03-28 03:10:00  0.00   0.0
5    A 2021-03-28 03:20:00  0.00   0.0
6    A 2021-03-28 03:30:00  0.14   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, what is `30T`?

Comment: @Fluxy  It's the rolling window size corresponding to 30 minutes.

Comment: If I get `ValueError: col2 must be monotonic`, do I understand correctly that in some rows in my real data the interval between sequential records is not 10 minutes?

Comment: @Fluxy  Is that your real data is not sorted in time sequence or not all in the same format ?

Comment: The `col2` is monotonic within the same `col1`. Is it a problem?

Comment: @Fluxy  Ok, so maybe need an extra grouping under Col1 then

Comment: @Fluxy  Give me little time to work on this additional constraint then.   Probably your time sequence reset with different value of Col1

Comment: @Fluxy  Revised codes above to cater for different grouping of `col1`.  Please try again.

Comment: @Fluxy  For the notation `30T`, you can refer to [this doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html)  and refer to the Parameter on `unit`.   Using this notion of specifying 30 minutes in rolling windows has the advantage that your data is not constrained to 10 minutes or 15 minutes intervals.  So long as you want to calculate for 30 minutes, it would get the correct number of intervals to refer to.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['col3'].rolling(4,min_periods=0).apply(lambda x: np.median(x[-4:-1])if x[-1]>5  else x[-1],raw=True)
```